# Count grid points with same sign across multiple xarray.DataArrays

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have the following three DataArrays each holding the correlation value at grid points across Africa (see ds1, ds2, ds3 below):

```
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 80, lon: 80)>
array([[       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       ...,
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.35216908, 0.35083426,
        0.34060067],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.26451613, 0.33259177,
        0.30723026],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.29477197, 0.26674082,
        0.25828699]])
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 -19.5 -18.5 -17.5 -16.5 -15.5 ... 56.5 57.5 58.5 59.5
  * lat      (lat) float64 -39.5 -38.5 -37.5 -36.5 -35.5 ... 36.5 37.5 38.5 39.5
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 80, lon: 80)>
array([[       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       ...,
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.23248053, 0.2676307 ,
        0.32502781],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.23515017, 0.21201335,
        0.27430478],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.17241379, 0.1483871 ,
        0.156396  ]])
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 -19.5 -18.5 -17.5 -16.5 -15.5 ... 56.5 57.5 58.5 59.5
  * lat      (lat) float64 -39.5 -38.5 -37.5 -36.5 -35.5 ... 36.5 37.5 38.5 39.5
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 80, lon: 80)>
array([[       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,
               nan],
       ...,
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.02424917, 0.05094549,
        0.09810901],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.14349277, 0.15951057,
        0.20711902],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 0.16440489, 0.22625139,
        0.22892102]])
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 -19.5 -18.5 -17.5 -16.5 -15.5 ... 56.5 57.5 58.5 59.5
  * lat      (lat) float64 -39.5 -38.5 -37.5 -36.5 -35.5 ... 36.5 37.5 38.5 39.5
```

Plotted they look like the following:
[image]

For each grid point, I would like to count the number of models (i.e. ds1, ds2, ds3) that agree on a positive/negative correlation. That is, for each grid point, I'd like to compare the sign of the value in ds1, ds2 and ds3 and count how many are positive/negative (to then create a plot that shows sign agreement across models). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your `DataArrays` cover the same grid, you can just combine them to a dataset and compute the occurrences.

```py
import xarray as xr

# testdata
xx =  xr.tutorial.load_dataset("rasm").Tair

# list of data arrays with same grid
darrs = [xx.to_dataset(name=x) for x in ("ds1", "ds2", "ds3")]

xx_combined = xr.merge(darrs, compat="no_conflicts")

# count positive values & sum over all models 
xx_res = (xx_comb > 0).to_array().sum(axis=0)

# plot
xx_res.plot.imshow()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this - yes my data is all on the same grid! I will certainly try it. A follow up question is that I also have the statistical significance of the correlation at each grid point in separate DataArrays (i.e. ds1_p, ds2_p, ds3_p). How would I only count up the values that are statistically significant? That is, I would like to count where the models are positive and statistically significant?

Comment: You probably have to calculate the significance for each pixel and then use it as a boolean mask to exclude non significant pixels. I'd say you ask a new question for that

Comment: Hi @Val when I tried your method above I get the following error: MergeError: conflicting values for variable 'cor' on objects to be combined. You can skip this check by specifying compat='override'. I don't think 'override' would do the correct thing. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like the arrays you want to merge are not compatible (maybe not the same grid?) Hard to say without more info about the data. But there's a lot of info about xarray MergeError and what causes it out there

Comment: Okay, I will have a look. Thanks.